# Treeview With Json Object

Tags: json, angular, tree, treeview

I have an Angular project and  a nested json file like below:
I want that "This json data must be imported from json file and a treeview must be loaded with that json object. How can I make this?

```
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "root": {
    "@title": "Basic Rules",
    "topic": [
      {
        "@id": "1",
        "@title": "Beginning",
      },
      {
        "@id": "2",
        "@title": "Purpose of Course",
      },
      {
        "@id": "3",
        "@title": "Basic Lessons",
        "topic": [
          {
            "@id": "4",
            "@title": "Lesson Content",
          }
          ]
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, that was answered here [tree view from json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194073/angular-tree-view-from-json-data)